# CA1508 - line is never 'null'. Remove or refactor the condition(s) to avoid dead code

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

Code Block in question:

```
using var content = new StringContent(
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(executeRequest, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase }),
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

if (this.oidcConfiguration.Enabled)
{
    this.httpClient.SetBearerToken(await this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token"));
}

var response = await this.httpClient.PostAsync(this.executionServiceHttpConfig.ExecuteUri, content);
```

I am getting this error:

> CA1508    'content = new StringContent(
> JsonSerializer.Serialize(executeRequest, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy =
> JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase }),
> System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)' is never 'null'. Remove or refactor the condition(s) to avoid dead code.

On this line:

```
using var content = new StringContent(
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(executeRequest, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase }),
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Where is the dead code? 
Can you please provide a new way to write this code such that the error will be eliminated?

Comment: Which (exact) versions of .NET and perhaps also Visual Studio are you using? You may need to update them to the latest builds. Rule CA1508 has been reported to [produce](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/2250) [false](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/4502) [positives](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/2985) in the past. I don't know if all such cases have been fixed by now.

Comment: .NET Core 6.0, Visual Studio Professional 2022 version 17.2.1